# vb.NET Create Attachment collection

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, attachment

Is there an easy and convenient was to create an attachment collection in vb.NET to hold a variety of attachment files such as .doc, .pdf, .jpg?

Comment: Define *attachment collection*.

Comment: A collection of files that can be referenced at a later time.  So it may be a collection of .doc files, mixed with .jpg, etc.

Comment: Do you want to store the files in memory? If yes, then you need a collection of byte arrays. Or a dictionary where the key is the file path/name and the value is a byte array. If no, then a collection of [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) objects could work.